# Partition Bootable Flash Drive

Tags: usb, partitioning, usb-flash-drive, bootable-media

I created a bootable flash drive with Chromium OS installed on it. However, Chromium OS only needs about 4GB of space, and my flash drive is 8GB.

I wanted to make the rest of the 4GB a FAT32 partition, but when I look at GParted, I have 12 different partitions on the flash drive with unallocated space scattered everywhere.

I made the bootable flash drive with Ubuntu Linux's usb-imagecreator. I run Ubuntu Linux 11.04 x86_64 and Windows 7 Professional 64-bit.

If any of you have experience with this, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, you'd have to flip the 'removable media' bit before you can partition it (which convinces windows its a regular USB HDD) - supposedly lexar bootit can do it, but its nearly impossible to find.